# I can't install TeamViewer in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, teamviewer

A few hours ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC.
How can I install TeamViewer if this isn't in Ubuntu Software?

Comment: The DEB package of TeamViewer for Ubuntu is here: https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb

Comment: What did you do and what failed?

Answer (score 6):

Go to the [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) website and hit the giant Download button.

That'll download a DEB file, which you can double-click to install.

Comment: Thanks, I already installed it, but I can't find it. Where should it be?

Comment: Search for it in Dash.

Comment: Than you very much !

Comment: @B.Fritz If this answer helped resolve your issue, please consider upvoting and accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the `*.deb` download on the Teamviewer website, download it, then run `dpkg -i teamviewer-package-name.deb` to install it. If you cannot find the `*.deb` file on the website, they probably don't support Ubuntu, though I believe they do.